# What does var1 means in this query

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY id  DESC LIMIT 20)var1 ORDER BY id ASC;
```

This query is working fine in MySql i cannot understand what does var1 means in this. This is alias or what

the reason behind using var1 over there in the query

Comment: Yes, `var1` is an alias, and every derived table must have an alias.

Comment: When you do a subquery it **must** have an alias, even if not used elsewhere, or else you get the `Every derived table must have its own alias` error. Pretty sure this is a dupe but haven't found one

Comment: Take it out see what happens..